# Как записать код в MBR флешки?

Tags: ассемблер, mbr

Нужно записать ассемблированный листинг по адресу 0000:7С00 . Как это сделать? Использую ос Windows

**Для тех, кому вопрос кажется очень общим:** Есть программа(ассемблерный листинг), нужно что б при bootинге с флешки выполнялась эта программа. Мне подсказали, что нужно ассемблерный листинг программы записать по вышеуказанному адресу. Как это сделать?

Comment: возможно, проще будет загрузить какой-нибудь live-дистрибутив *gnu/linux* и выполнить элементарную команду `# cp файл устройство`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но мне нужно по конкретному адресу записать

Comment: @АртурКлочко, `ddrescue` умеет, вроде.

Comment: @АртурКлочко, видимо, я неправильно понял, что вы подразумеваете под «адресом» (подумал, что это начало и конец, а не просто `7c00`). тогда надо выполнить очень-очень сложную команду: `# dd if=файл of=устройство bs=1 seek=31744` (последнее число — это `7c00` в десятичной с.с.). [dd](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd)

Comment: О, спасибо, попробую!

Answer (score -1):

Вот сдесь, то что мне нужно, своя мини-ос 
http://citforum.ru/programming/digest/realhello.shtml